# is something like 'core local storage' possible?

Tags: linux, multithreading

I know there's `thread local storage (TLS)` for threads, however, is there something like `core local storage` for each core in multi-core environment ?

Comment: Given as a process can be moved between cores without warning or notice, how would you build consistent logic using this facility, even if it existed?

Comment: Also, anything in your L1 cache is going to get flushed during process switching, so what would be the point?

Comment: ...which is to say: No such facility exists, and it would be pointless if it did. If you want to ensure locality on that level, pin a thread to a core, and prevent anything else from using that same core, and you have the desired effect using only things that actually exist.

Comment: Having said that: It's certainly _possible_, if someone actually had a justification for it.

Answer (score 1):

Since a thread can be moved from core to core without warning, there doesn't seem to be any obvious use for such a capability.

Answer (score 0):

Does it exist? As others have said there's really no point for it that I can see.

But can you build something like that? Oh very simple just grab some memory and index it with the cpu.id, there's no magic behind thread local storage either.

If you're trying to improve performance, just consider that thread local storage well be exclusively in one cores cache which is pretty much just as well and has the advantage of adapting to changing cores cheaply.